# How to use unique_ptr fo automatic memory management?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I want a memory block that I can resize, so using the C library functions:

```cpp
{
  char *buf = reinterpret_cast<char*>(std::malloc(n));
  ⋮
  std::realloc(buf,N);
  ⋮
  std::free(buf);
}
```

How can I go about using smart pointer protection (against leaking `buf`) in the above snippet?

If I replace the first instruction with this:

```
uBuf = std::make_unique<char[]>(n); char *buf = uBuf.get();
```

Would that "free" me from worrying about the final `free()`?
Would the `std::unique_ptr` tolerate resizing its *raw protégé (no longer `n` bytes) and do the `delete[]` expected from it when leaving the scope ?

If not, how to do it?

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<char>` or a `std::string` instead?

Comment: std::vector<char> if you need to resize - or maybe std::string depending on just what you are doing with it.

Comment: In C++ you would use `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` here and only `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` if you have very specific requirements.

Comment: Using low-level APIs that deal in char*, and malloc/realloc code is *very* efficient  (with realloc leaving alone the beginning of the buffer, and other considerations).

Comment: Using `realloc` with `unique_ptr` would be interesting. `unique_ptr` owns the `malloc`ed allocation, but not necessarily the `realloc`ed allocation. Carnage will likely ensue.

Comment: Side note: All of the groovy `realloc` tricks used to save work are probably already being used by the `std::string` and `std::vector` implementations.

Comment: Can't pass vectors to system APIs.

Comment: But you can usually pass `std::vector::data`.

Comment: There are cases where what you're asking about makes sense. Sometimes you do have to hyper-tune past the generalizations the Standard library has to put up with, but it's a lot of work. Make sure you need to do it (profile), and it's that special case that's worth asking about. The generalized case is always going to be met with "Save time. Use `vector`." answers.

Comment: @user4581301 :  you think I can pass `*const* std::vector::data` to `StringCchCatW()` that would modify it ??

Comment: [`data`'s not `const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data), but it [used to be for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). When it is `const`, I've yet to find a `string` implementation where `&str[0]` failed even though it's not 100% kosher.

Comment: I'm instinctively reluctant to feed poor old `StringCchCatW()` (and even older APIs) a `vector::data` !  (access, contiguous buffer,..). Would definitely try it as last resort.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 There is no difference between the pointer returned from `vector::data` and a raw pointer to a memory block. In situations where passing the latter would be appropriate passing the former works just as well. Only difference is that the default allocator of `std::vector` will have allocated the memory with `operator new`, not with `malloc`. That would probably only matter if you have alignment requirements that need to be satisfied. (And in practice `operator new` will call `malloc` for anything not over-aligned anyway.)

Comment: I'm totally going to try this. I'm already a big fan of vector "to rule'em all", but this would push it up a notch towards the God status !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would "free" me from worrying about the final free() ?

Yes, it will correctly call `delete[]` for you.

> Would the unique_ptr tolerate resizing its *raw protégé (no longer n bytes) and do the delete[] expected from it when leaving the scope ?

Calling `realloc` on the raw pointer causes undefined behavior, because it was not allocated with `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`, but with `new[]`.

To make this work correctly, you need to use a custom deleter which calls `free` instead of `delete[]`. Then you need to allocate the pointer manually instead of using `std::make_unique`, so that the allocation comes from `malloc`. Then to handle ownership during the `realloc` call you need to release the owned pointer, call realloc, check its return value for failure, and then conditionally hand ownership back to the smart pointer, e.g.:

```
struct FreeDeleter {
    void operator()(void* p) const noexcept { std::free(p); }
};

template<typename T>
// C++20 constraint to assure free is appropriate for the type
requires std::is_trivial_v<std::remove_all_extents_t<T>>
using free_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, FreeDeleter>;

//...

auto buf = free_unique_ptr<char[]>(static_cast<char*>(std::malloc(n)));

//...

auto buf_raw = buf.release(); // after this `buf` does not own the buffer anymore
if(auto buf_new = std::realloc(buf_raw, N)) {
    buf.reset(static_cast<char*>(buf_new));
} else {
    // realloc failed, return ownership of the old pointer
    buf.reset(buf_raw);
    // handle failure here as appropriate
}
```

You would probably want to wrap the whole sequence in a function (and the allocation line maybe as well) to avoid mistakes in there. This would be an "unsafe" block where temporarily the smart pointer does not guarantee the deletion (because the pointer is released).

---

As already mentioned in the comments, this is worth it only if a simple `std::vector` or `std::string` doesn't do it. Implementations for these two do not typically use `realloc`, even for trivial types, as far as I know, but how worth `realloc` instead of copying to a new allocation immediately is will depend on the allocator used.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Too much overhead, though. I promise not to forget a `free(buf)` at end of scope !

Comment: I've seen some pretty funky `vector`s. One was a combination of `malloc`, `realloc`, and placement `new`. Been years since I looked at the mainstream `vector` implementations, though. Now-a-days I'd expect "the weird stuff" to be bundled up inside a custom allocator.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 "_Too much overhead_": Are you referring to the `free_unique_ptr` approach? There should be almost no overhead over what you are already doing. In the reallocation part there is theoretically an extra zeroing of the internal pointer in `buf` and a branch to `free` on the `reset`, but the branch is never taken (though the compiler might have difficulty seeing this through the `realloc` call and may not optimize it away depending on the context).

Comment: @user4581301 I might be wrong, but I don't remember seeing `realloc` being used in e.g. recent libc++ and libstdc++. I think I read in a standard proposal that it turns out modern `malloc` allocation algorithms usually don't allow `realloc` to expand allocations far (or at all), so that it is not usually worth it to try to, given that the container itself will typically multiply the old size by a factor anyway.

Comment: Agreed. I was referring to code size (->maintenance, bugs, mental load..). My whole approach is to place myself under the protection of an backstage sentinel (one off call) and enjoy life risk free. Not to have it fight for center stage all along `buf`'s adventures..

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Might not be worth it for a one-off case, but if you use this pattern multiple times, after wrapping the allocation line and the reallocation block in functions, you will actually reduce the code at the call site (maybe significantly). Instead of `malloc`/`realloc`/`free` you will have only `my_malloc`/`my_realloc` and as bonus it is easy to make this generic and type-safe, e.g. if you need to do the same for an array of `int`.

Comment: I see. Still, a `realloc()` is then replaced with `my_realloc() / release() / realloc() / reset()`. If performance is not truly critical, you're actually right.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 It would be possible to modify the example in such a way to give the compiler enough information to always optimize the `release`/`reset` away (or to a simple pointer assignment). That requires reordering things a bit so that it won't really look safe, but that should be fine with some comments. First you would need to get the pointer with `auto buf_raw = buf.get();`. Then you would need to call `realloc` on the pointer and if there is no failure call `buf.release()` without storing the result followed by `buf.reset(buf_new)`.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 See the assembly output: https://godbolt.org/z/fhWPbYTd1

Comment: The lower-level memory managers are a lot smarter these days as well. They don't want to do extra work either, so a lot of the cheats we used to do in the code are pretty much irrelevant. Virtual memory and a 64 bit address space can allow you to be really efficient by being grotesquely wasteful.

Comment: @user17732522 : I already agreed, but seeing is believing. That's actually 4 assembly instructions ! (aside from the necessary function call mgmt). Sold. Trying it right now (if only my better half would leave me alone.. unfortunate news from UK :( ).

Comment: Implementation in a small concatenation routine : https://godbolt.org/z/rGav4vfe5

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 I have only looked at the part transformed from my example:  I mixed the triviality test up. That is fixed now. There is no point to the `try`/`catch` around `realloc`. It is impossible for it to throw (since it is a C library function). It indicates bad alloc by returning a null pointer which is why the error handling goes in the `else` branch of the `if`. As I suggested you should probably wrap the allocation in a function too, to avoid type mismatch between `sizeof`, the template argument and the `static_cast`.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Also, since it looks like you are using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, beware that `realloc` will _not_ zero the additional memory as `calloc` does.

Comment: @ExpertNoob1 Also a minor issue, the multiplication `N*sizeof(T)` is prone to overflow, which can potentially lead to vulnerabilities if `N` can be user-controlled. That's why e.g. `std::allocator` and `new` expressions add a check that `N` is smaller than `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()/sizeof(T)`, otherwise throwing `std::bad_array_new_length`.

Comment: Thank you for the code review. You're right about catching try{old C routines}, doesn't make sense (although, making these throw in C++ coud be a good idea). Too eager to get the "good part" (unique_ptr effect :). In my mind, urealloc() is a "template of 2" (char & wchar_t), not worried about sizeof for trivial types. calloc() is intentional, used on the first 2 bytes only : StringCchCatW() looks for 0 in buffer and starts "cat"ting there. After that, realloc() can write whatever, as long as the existing 0 mark is left alone (no need for more expensive calloc()).

Comment: If the user tricks strlen() into returning 2^53 or something, realloc()==0 will cause a graceful return. This is clearly intended for concatenating a few strings, so setting a reasonable limit on input size is a good idea (a book is 1 million chars, ~2MB of wchar_ts, 1 page (~2500 chars) is enough !).